# How to conduct iterative steps with multiple data frames in python ?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I collected some data in the lab and it is stored in multiple excel sheets. I loaded the excel sheets into data frames and now I want to perform the same function for each data frame but i am not sure how.

```
df = pd.read_csv("TRSCE_5_1.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv("TRSCE_5_2.csv")

def Function_plot() :  
    X = df[["Frequency(Hz)"]].values
    y = df[" R(Ohm)-data"].values
    y1 = df[" X(Ohm)-data"].values
    plt.title("Resistance vs. Frequency")
    plt.plot(X, y, label = 'Resistance')
    plt.plot(X, y1, label= 'Reactance')
    plt.ylabel('ylabel')
    plt.xlabel('xlabel')
    plt.legend()

    plt.xlabel("Frequency", size=20)
    plt.ylabel("Resistance", size=20)
for each df in [df,df1,df2...,df8]
    Function_plot(df)
```

Comment: what are the headers in your csv file? Can you post an example?

Comment: Do you realize that Function_plot() is always calling the df associated with TRSCE_T_1.csv? This is because your def Function_plot() does not specify an argument

Comment: Ahhhh now i see, Thanks @kevinkayaks. I got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
    import glob

    pattern = 'TRSCE*.csv'

    csv_files = glob.glob(pattern)

    df_list = []

    for csv in csv_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(csv)

        # Fill the data frame list
        df_list.append(df)

        # Plot the data frame using your user defined function
        Function_plot(df)
```

Note that in the last line above your user function is modified to accept a single data frame argument. So the signature of your function needs to change to:

```
    def Function_plot(df)
        # then the function body
```

I noticed that the syntax of your for loop in your code has a mistake. If you want to plot in a separate loop then use:

```
    for each in df_list:
        Function_plot(each)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code. I got it working by using the codes.